# Java Enum static method thread safety?

Tags: java, enums

I have a use case where, iterating the Java enum and test, the argument contain in the enum list, It's a static method, Is this thread safe?

```
public enum EnumType {

    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    FIVE;

    public static boolean isValid(String input) {
        for (EnumType type : EnumType.values()) {
            if (input.equals(type.toString())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the thread-safety concern? There's no obvious shared state here.

Comment: It seems this method is thread-safe. There is no mutation of anything here.

Comment: Isn't the EnumType values shared?. Or they have a own copy in their own execution thread?

Comment: @Lino I think you got what I'm looking for "EnumType.values() returns a copy". Thanks.

Comment: @ArunaKarunarathna There are no thread safety concerns when there are no mutation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EnumType.values()` returns a copy of all enum constants, so even if you would modify the array returned by `values()` it would not influence any other threads.

The byte code confirms this:

```
public static values()[Lcom/example/EnumType;
 L0
  LINENUMBER 43 L0
  GETSTATIC com/example/EnumType.$VALUES : [Lcom/example/EnumType;
  INVOKEVIRTUAL [Lcom/example/EnumType;.clone ()Ljava/lang/Object;
  CHECKCAST [Lcom/example/EnumType;
  ARETURN
  MAXSTACK = 1
  MAXLOCALS = 0
```

The line:

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL [Lcom/example/EnumType;.clone ()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Invokes the `Array.clone()` method, which returns a shallow copy of the array

Comment: exactly the reason why it's a constant... if `values` would  return the *actual* array that is backed by the the enum, there is nothing stopping me doing `.values()[1] = null`...

Answer (score 3):

You method is thread-save, because you are not mutating any state and each call to `EnumType.values()` returns a new copy, so multiple calls to this method at the same time do not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 2):

The `isValid()` method does not modify any of the values. As it is just an iteration you don't need to think of thread safety. Always make sure to check for threadsafety whenever writes and reads happen concurrently. In such cases `synchronized` key word can be used for methods whenever required. But in this case you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly safe.
Because it just checks the value and returns true, false.
You do not have to worry because your methods do not access shared instance resources or change values.
However, in a multithreaded environment, the following situations can be problematic:

```
Class IndexStore {
   public static int index = -1;
}  

public enum EnumType {

    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    FIVE;

    public static boolean isValid(String input) {
        for (EnumType type : EnumType.values()) {
            if (input.equals(type.toString())) {
                IndexStore.index = type.ordinal();
                return true;
            }
        }

        IndexStore.index = -1;
        return false;
    }
}
```